# How do I delete data/characters from a file?

Tags: winapi

I'm writing a program to edit a txt file.

But I found that the windows API WriteFile can only add data/characters to a file, but not deleting data from files.

The only solution I've come up is to read the whole file into a buffer using ReadFile, and then use a loop to shift the data one by one, then replace the old file with the new file. But I think this will probably make my program really slow.

Can anyone help please

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're trying to delete from the end of the file it can be very fast with `truncate()` and `ftruncate()`.

Where are you trying to delete the data from?  If it's from the middle, you'll have to use `fseek()`:  If the file contains "ABCDEFG", and you want to delete "DEF", use `fseek()` to get to G, copy "G" into a buffer, `fseek` to where "C" is, then `write()` what's there.  Then truncate the file to the correct size with `ftruncate()`.

If this really becomes a performance issue for you, you'll want to either design your file in a way that accounts for this or use a database of some kind.  You may also want to use memory-mapped files, but usually this is better done by a database that someone else wrote instead of reinventing the wheel.

Comment: thanks for quick reply LaceCard! =]
but which method are generally used by a text editor like notepad.exe?
thanks!

Comment: Well notepad.exe already has the contents of the file in memory.  So it probably just writes everything out from the beginning when you hit save.  I/O performance isn't much of an issue with text editors since you're dealing with a few megabytes at most.

Comment: thanks LaceCard!
I think I'm gonna use memory-mapping. But in my case, another program is also editing the file. Will this cause any synchronization issue?
thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Files are linear streams of data. If you want to remove content from a file, you must re-write all the content of the file that follows the part that you have remove. So, unless the content to be removed is at the end of the file, you will need to perform some writing. In the worst case scenario, in order to remove the first byte of a file, you need to re-write the entire file apart from the byte that you removed.

FWIW, Raymond Chen wrote a nice article on this subject: [How do I delete bytes from the beginning of a file?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2010/12/01/10097859.aspx)

Comment: thanks David Heffeman.

actually I'm mainly dealing with deleting data from the middle of a file. But It is quite a good article to improve my knowledge. And I think the conclusion is "I must rewrite everything beyond the deleted part" as you said.
thanks you very much!=]